# How to set 1st arg type optionality based on other arg type in typescript

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I want to create function that takes 2 curried arguments.

- 1st arg - Could be object with specific properties (`TParam`) or `void`
- 2nd arg - Should be object with specific properties (`TParam`) or object without that properties (`TParam`), if 1st arg type is -  `TParam`.

Eventually i want to `TParam` type be passed in any argument but not twice

Here is my best 'not' working solution..

```
type TParam = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const param: TParam = { a: "string", b: "string" };

type Check<T> = T extends TParam ? void : TParam

const example = <T extends TParam>(arg0?: T) => (arg1: Check<T>) => {
    if (typeof arg0 === 'object') {
        return arg0;
    }

    return arg1;
}

const ok = example()(param)  // Wrong
const ok1 = example(param)() // Ok

const error = example({})()  // Ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). 
The following is a working example.  You can also try it out at this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=58#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgCgQwE4ILZQLxQN5QLABQUxUCAXFAM7BICWAdgOYDchJUARhdXU8-gQC%20hQgGMA9vWpQwyNBXhz0WXOSgAiHg0bqANJwqaa29VEGsChAGYBXeqOC1JUCAA80YADYQAFK4WIKKgAlBQ%20wZgAfLCBaPzWdg5O9C7uqF6%20oVB%20AUoRGNGKQfEEtvaOzm4e3n4A-LlBEbjEbCS0Vn5NrezESBDANkgp4VFQriTdZhNEJBCelNDYk%20x9A0PZ-jF5o%20MtM8SCAodiktLiANaYqdWZPrKNJAD0j1AAcuIuSEjiSAISUsAoBcAIxXKrpGr3NDBEZQZ5vD4QL4-P6nQFI76-LDgjI%20bCCGERYjwgCiyKQ%20gA7gALWiialQWiUVKQBwQAAmQA).

```
type TParam = { 
    a: string;
    b: string; 
}

const param: TParam = { a: "string", b: "string" };

function example(x: TParam): () => TParam; 
function example(): (x: TParam) => TParam; 
function example(x?: TParam) {   
    if(x) {
        return () => x   
    }   
    else {
        return (x: TParam) => x   
    } 
} 
const ok = example()(param)   // No error 
const ok1 = example(param)()  // No error 
const error = example({})()   // Error, which is expected
```